# Web dynamic project, Instance the same instance

Tags: java

I'm working on a web project, I have a class named Connection, this class establishes a connection via TCP/IP with another device, When there is a http get request I instance an object "connection_o" and start a thread to keep the communication up like this: "connection_o.start" so the connection is established, in the next http request I must send a message, but when I execute again the "doGet" in order to avoid the nullpointer exception I need to instance the object again , but I can't because I need to use the same instance that I used before that is running, in my tests, the connection keeps working but I´m unable to access to the thread I already created.  So I need some kind of static class or a way to use the thread that is already running.

This is the code for the socket

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Provider extends Thread{

    ServerSocket providerSocket;
    Socket connection = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;
    Provider(){}


    public void run()
    {
        try{
            //1. creating a server socket
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
            //2. Wait for connection
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            //3. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            sendMessage("Connection successful");
            //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
            do{
                try{
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                //  System.out.println("client>" + message);



                    if (message.equals("cambio la variable"))
                        System.out.println("Abriendo Puerta");
                    //  sendMessage("bye");
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                    System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
                }
            }while(!message.equals("bye"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //4: Closing connection
            try{
                in.close();
                out.close();
                providerSocket.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioException){
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
        //  System.out.println("server>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the doGet

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 

throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s = request.getParameter("s");
        //Routine to send blink to RPi
    if (s.equals("Start")){
      Provider c = new Provider();
      c.Inicio();
    }

    if (s.equals("Send")){

          c.sendMessage("Blink");
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help me help you, it would be great to see the code you're trying to run.

Comment: store it in HttpSession?

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan I already updated the code.

Comment: @happymeal I already look for that but it is no clear for me, could you please explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I assume is, that HTTP is a stateless protocol. That means by default the server does not know anything about the client.

That is where `Sessions`come in place. On your initial request you have to initialize a session for the client who made the request. From then you are able to "recognize" the client on requests (e.g. to restore the clients state).

You also have to save the "connection" inside the session context. You may want to consider using so called "Connection Pools" because it could be very complicated to handle all established connection and close them properly (e.g. session timeout etc.)

I suggest you read basics about the HTTP protocol, Sessions and (e.g. Database)Connetion-Handling.

Comment: But I can find a straight forward Documentation. Thanks Very Much

Comment: I already understand about, but I think It will not work by that way because the session is established via browser and this is a socket connection with a RaspberryPi. What do you think?  Many thanks

Comment: I guess you only need one Provider, right? The one which communicates to the RasperiPI. So simply create a "Singleton" instance of the Provider and handle the `establish connection` and `close connection` automatically. On `doGet(...)` do something like this `Provider.getInstance().sendMessage("Blink")`. In the `getInstance()` method you then create a new provider, if you don't already have one, and establish the connection. If you already have one, simply reuse that Provider. The connection should already be established. If not, re-establish.

Comment: But, I can do that in the first execution of the doGet, in the second one the connection is established as you say, but how can I reuse that connection that is already created? Because in the first step the connection is established for the two devices so both are hearing and sending messages. I need a way to use the methods of the instance that I created in the first execution of the doGet. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused. What are you trying to do (in simple words please). What is a device? How many devices do you have. For what do you need the web server in the first place? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, I will be as clear as I can, I´m using a Rpi with java and I made a connection via TCP/IP socket to a PC, The Raspberry has several peripherals connected, some sensors and actuators, so the whole idea is to send and receive data from the Rpi to  a PC in order to control some process. I test the communication in a "main" and it works properly because when I instance "Provider" it creates the instance and never destroys it until the application ends so I can use the method sendMessage freely because the instance already has the "in" & "out" objects for Communi

Comment: Communication. When I use the web project which is needed for my final application, the problem begins , Imagine two buttons in the view, one to start communication and other to send messages, so when the user presses the first button it will start the socket and establish the communication, and when he presses the second one it will use send message method but I can not refer to the same connection that I already created when the first button was pressed, I can not start and close the communication because it must be permanent.My doubt is how to refer to the same instance that I reated before

Comment: Okay. I understand, I have another question. If a user (user 1) clicked "connect" (Button 1) and then click "do Something" (Button 2) is the "do Something" a stateful or stateless call. Means Could another user (user 2) also use the same connection from user 1, or does she need its own connection?

Comment: Every user start a new connection, but the connection must be the same always. I was searching for the Singleton, and I think is the solution but that is a kind of method of a class or a kind of class? Thanks

Comment: If every user needs its own connection, singleton design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) IS NOT the answer! If that is really what you need, I do not think your choice of `architecture` is the right one at all. You really should re-consider before going any further with your implementation

Answer (score 0):

May be you can keep the

```
Provider c = new Provider();
```

as an instance variable of the servlet class and change the code :

```
if (s.equals("Start")){
      c.Inicio();
    }
```

**Note :** In this case you need to take care of the thread safety. Because now `c.Inicio()` would be called by multiple request threads at a time.

Comment: But the thing is, any time I run the doGet method it will try to make the connection again, but it is already established. Thanks

Comment: As you have mentioned you want to continue with the same connection and do not want to create a new object. Would you please elaborate your view point?

Comment: Your Servlet instance will be a singleton, please keep this in mind.